# React set state working partially even though it is updated

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have below handleNSMOptions function which gets called from onChange. I'm using Material UI Switch component. I have four such Switch components and each has onChange handler. Initially all are in unchecked state. My requirement is to check either of the first two Switch components i.e., if I check first Switch, then it needs to check if second Switch is checked, if so uncheck the second Switch and if I check second Switch, then it needs to check if first Switch is checked, if so uncheck the first Switch. The third and fourth Switch are normal.

If one of the first two Switch components are checked and when onChange handler is called on first Switch component to check it unchecks the second Switch component but the first Switch is not updated to check. I'm not able to figure out where is the mistake. Can you please help me to figure out?

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import {
  FormControlLabel,
  FormGroup,
  Switch,
  Tooltip,
  Typography
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import NSMService from '../../services/nsm/NSMService';
import { addNotification } from '../notification/NotificationManager';
import _ from 'lodash';


const EditNSM = (props) => {

  const [nsmOptionsState, setNSMOptionsState] = useState({
    matchWords: props.nsmSavedOptions.matchWords !== 0,
    matchName: props.nsmSavedOptions.matchName !== 0,
    physicalToLogical: props.nsmSavedOptions.physicalToLogical !== 0,
    active: props.nsmSavedOptions.active !== 0,
  });

  const [nsmInitialOptionsState] = useState(nsmOptionsState);

  const handleNSMOptions = (event) => {
    console.log('target name: ', event.target.name);
    console.log('target checked: ', event.target.checked);
    console.log('matchName: ', nsmOptionsState.matchName);
    console.log('matchWords: ', nsmOptionsState.matchWords);
    if (event.target.name === 'matchWords' && event.target.checked === true && nsmOptionsState.matchName === true) {
      setNSMOptionsState({...nsmOptionsState, matchWords: true})
      setNSMOptionsState({...nsmOptionsState, matchName: false})
    } else if (event.target.name === 'matchName' && event.target.checked === true && nsmOptionsState.matchWords === true) {
      setNSMOptionsState({...nsmOptionsState, matchName: true})
      setNSMOptionsState({...nsmOptionsState, matchWords: false})
    } else {
      setNSMOptionsState({...nsmOptionsState, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked});
    }
    console.log('nsmOptionsState', nsmOptionsState)
  }

  const saveNSMOptions = () => {

    if (_.isEqual(nsmOptionsState, nsmInitialOptionsState)) {
      addNotification('success', 'No changes made');
      props.setEditDialog(false);
    } else {
     
      let nsmOptions = new FormData();
      nsmOptions.append('matchWords', nsmOptionsState.matchWords ? 1 : 0);
      nsmOptions.append('matchName',  nsmOptionsState.matchName ? 1 : 0);
      nsmOptions.append('physicalToLogical', nsmOptionsState.physicalToLogical ? 1 : 0);
      nsmOptions.append('active', nsmOptionsState.active ? 1 : 0);
      nsmOptions.append('id', props.nsmSavedOptions.id);
    
      saveNSMOptionsAction(nsmOptions, props.nsmName);
     
    }
  }

  const saveNSMOptionsAction = (nsmOptions, nsmName) => {
    NSMService.saveNSMOptions(nsmOptions)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.data.substring(0, 1) === '0') {
          addNotification('success', `NSM Options for '${nsmName.length > 30 ? 
            nsmName.substring(0, 30) + '...' : nsmName}' saved successfully`);
          props.setRefresh(props.nsmSavedOptions.id);
          props.getNSMFilesData();
        } else {
          addNotification('error', response.data.substring(2));
        }
        props.setEditDialog(false);
        props.setNSMRowSelection([]);
        
      }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <FormGroup column>
          <div>
            <Tooltip
              title={props.nsmName}
              placement={props.nsmName.length > 20 ? 'right-start' : 'bottom'}
              arrow
            >
              <Typography
                variant="h6"
              >
                {props.nsmName.length > 20 ? props.nsmName.substring(0, 20) + '...' : props.nsmName}
              </Typography>
           </Tooltip>
          </div>
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Switch
                  checked={nsmOptionsState.matchWords}
                  onChange={handleNSMOptions}
                  name="matchWords"
                />
              }
              label="Match Whole Words Only"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Switch
                  checked={nsmOptionsState.matchName}
                  onChange={handleNSMOptions}
                  name="matchName"
                />
              }
              label="Match Whole Name Only"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Switch
                  checked={nsmOptionsState.physicalToLogical}
                  onChange={handleNSMOptions}
                  name="physicalToLogical" />
              }
              label="Physical To Logical"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Switch
                  checked={nsmOptionsState.active}
                  onChange={handleNSMOptions}
                  name="active" />
              }
              label="Is Active"
            />
        </FormGroup>
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          marginTop: '10px'
        }}
      >
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          size='large'
          onClick={saveNSMOptions}
          // disabled={loading}
        >
          Save
        </Button>
      </div>
      </>
  );
}

export default EditNSM;
```

Comment: React batches state changes for efficiency's sake. However, this can mean if the state is something like an array or object and you call set state multiple times in a row while spreading other properties/values, you may only get the last state change taking effect. You can look into why this happens by googling about setting state in a loop for the standard example/explanation of this odd behaviour, but long story short you shouldn't be calling `setNSMOptionsState` twice in a row, set both `matchName` and `matchWords` in a single call to `setNSMOptionsState`

Comment: Yes updating in single call worked.